# Getting text from list using Context Menu

Tags: android, android-listview, android-contextmenu

I've been trying to get text from a row on my list using context menu. So far I was able to get the text back which was name using the id from my row.xml file. But when I select another row on my list it will get the same name back contained in the first row of the list and not the one I selected.

```
 public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
 {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();

    if(item.getTitle()=="Get")
    {
        TextView textView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.names); 
        String text = textView.getText().toString(); 

        //Then pass value retrieved from the list to the another activity 
    }
 }
```

row.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/names"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/pNumbers"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use `String.equals` or `String.equalsIgnoreCase` for comparing Strings instead of `==`

Answer (score 2):

That's not the proper way to do that. You should use [AdapterContextMenuInfo.position](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo.html#position) to get the index of the data in the list, and then pass that data to the new Activity.

```
AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();    
switch(item.getItemId()) { // using the id is the proper way to determine the menu item
    case R.id.menu_get:
        Object data = mListAdapter.getItem(info.position);
        // do something interesting with the data
        return true;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Was getId() suppose to be getItemId()? Also does "menu_get" associate to a xml file that contains the menu items? I created my context menu programmatically.

Comment: Yeah it should be getItemId(). Why do that instead of using xml? You can still assign an id if you create it programmatically.

Comment: I am quite new to Android I was following a tutorial that shows how to create context menu and it was done programmatically, I changed my code to use xml for menus now. I still don't quite know how to get the text using the info position to get the text I want.

Comment: info.position is the index of the item in the list that you long pressed on. So you use it to get the data behind the item that has the text you want.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested info.position

Then from adapter position you can retrieve all list item data.